# Repetition of the type : adjective1+ noun or adjective2 + noun

Tags: repetition

The question seems simple but so far I do not have a response. I'm wondering how to avoid the following type of repetition :

adjective1+ noun or adjective2 + noun

For instance (2 examples) :

1- "..a green car or a red car"

2-"It corresponds to a lower bound change or an upper bound change"

Here "car" and "change" are repeated twice. Can we change that to

1- "..a green or red car"

2-"It corresponds to a lower or an upper bound change"

It looks like we are loosing something by this reformulation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, at least in the examples you gave.  What you may be losing in some cases is **intelligibility**.  Just because something is grammatically correct does not mean it is the most comprehensible way to communicate the idea.

Comment: Nicely put. The horse raced past the barn fell down. And as for Buffalo ...